# MCP3204 problem with SPI comunication

Tags: adc, spi, pullup

I have problem with the [MCP3204](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/21298e.pdf) ADC. I am trying to connect 8 devices by SPI. A single device works perfectly, but if I try to attach the second MCP3204 it doesn't work. On a logic analyzer I can see strange voltage levels on MISO.

[image]

I tried with pull-up resistors, but that doesn't work either. It works with two MCPs, but it doesn't work with three.

Should I connect a pull-up resistor to all MCP3204 devices, or only one near the uC?

The MCP is connected to the uC via galvanic isolation. Should I pull up between uC and galvanic isolation, or between galvanic isolation and MCP3204? Maybe something else is wrong (but a single MCP works perfectly)?

Did someone have a similar problem with SPI?

Piece of schematic below:

[image]

[image]

---

Look if only one MCP is powered it is about 1.0V offset in idle on MISO.
[image]

if I powered two MCP3204 it is about 0.1V offset in idle on MISO and high state of MISO is under logical 1 limit so uC see don't see it
[image]

Looks like pull-up pull-down conflict? But now I don't have any pull-up/ pull/down

Comment: Looks like a bus fight (one chip pulling high and another pulling low). The strange thing is with /CS high on a target device, that device should tri-state MISO. Are you sure nothing else is connected?

Comment: How are these 8 devices connected to SPI master? Are they on the same bus serially or they have 8 SPI lines for each in parallel? If they are on the same serial bus. The Chip select signal may be causing the problem. Try to separate chip select signal manual by using GPIOs for that.  You can post some information about your interface which shows how those 8 devices are connected.

Comment: I suspect that it is pulling high or pulling down on all MCP3204 is depends on LSB. Last bit is hold after the transmission is completed. If LSB in one device is 0 it hold 0, and if in other device LSB is 1, this device hold 1 and it is a conflict. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @AmitM yes, 8 devices connected to SPI (parallel). STM32 is master. Chip select is sotfware controll.

Comment: Gregor, you have to use separate chip select sigan with separate GPIO pins for 8 devices. Dont use pull up resistor on CS and clock signals.

Comment: @AmitM I use 8 different GPIOs  (CS) for each MCP3204. It works separately but not together.

Comment: From which point is the measurement made? On ADC side or MCU side? Are multiple VOUTD output pins connected together to MCU MISO input? Or is there only one isolator for multiple ADCs?

Comment: @Gregor - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself and don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, please edit the question to add new information & clarifications. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules.) Thanks.

Comment: MISO must be high between transactions via pull-up on the ADC side. Is there one isolator per ADC or only one for all?

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the problem.
The problem was not in the SPI transmission, but with ADUM7441 digital isolation. The output of ADUM (MISO) is not tri-state (high impedance). So It was a problem on my PCB with electrical connection. I add schottky diode to all ADUMs isolation and pull-up resistor on MISO between uC and ADUMS and  pull-up resistors between all ADUM and MCP3204. Now it works perfectly.
Thank you for your help.